# WordPress Keywords

Tags: wordpress, keyword

Здравствуйте!
Нужно из записей вытащить **метки** и представить их как **keywords**.

*Пробовал вот так:*

```
<?php if (is_single()) {
if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post();
$strKeys="";
$posttags = get_the_tags();
if ($posttags) {
foreach($posttags as $tag) { $strKeys=$strKeys.$tag->name.', ';}
}
endwhile;
endif;
}
else {
$strKeys="ключевые слова для главной страницы";
}
?>
<meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo $strKeys; ?>">
```

*В HTML выводится следующее:*

```
<meta name="keywords" content="работа, учёба, отдых, ">
```

**Вопрос:** как у последнего кейворда убрать запятую?

Знаю, что можно использовать плагины (типа *All in One SEO Pack*), но хочется всё-таки без плагина обойтись.
Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
substr($strKeys,0,strlen($strKeys)-1);
```

а еще лучше вот так mb_substr($strKeys,0,mb_strlen($strKeys)-1);- операция над строками в многобайтовой кодировке

Comment: Спасибо. Я как раз только что сам до этого додумался. Всё равно спасибо :)

Comment: Я только вот так сделал: <meta name="keywords" content="<?php echo substr($strKeys, 0, -2); ?>">